# how to replace only the first word in regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex, expression

i want to ask how we can replace only the first word in regular expression in python
i do this code :

```
print "number of all KSU occurrences %i "%len(re.findall("ksu",string,re.IGNORECASE))
print "number of all KSU at end lof line %i"%len(re.findall("ksu\n",string,re.IGNORECASE))
```

and this is my txt file

> hello i'm student in KSU
>   i love ksu  , i like ksu , i KSU ksu KSU

i just want to replace only first ksu ( ignoring case ) into King Saud University

Comment: So, how do you like KSU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`re.sub()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) takes a `count` parameter:

```
re.sub(r"\bksu\b", "King Saud University", string, flags=re.I, count=1)
```